# Zoom Out type UIView in Objective C

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiviewanimation

I have a UIView in my viewcontroller. On a button click I want to show a zoom out effect of that view without changing any proportions of size. HOw to do that.

I want an effect like this

[image: First view]

[image: On Button click]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

apply affineTransform of scale .

```
 self.view.transform =CGAffineTransformMakeScale(.5, .5);
```

Apply this transform outside viewDidLoad. enclose inside UIView animation block to animate it.

Comment: @NithinMKeloth right side?

Comment: no how to make it back to previous state  self.view.transform =CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1);  ??

Comment: yes. if you try it, you will know.